# Display a new content everyday with FlutterFlow

Tags: flutter, flutterflow

I am trying to create an app that displays new content every day. This content would come from a Firestore Database and it would be shown on "Today's" section depending on the date.
You can take the [DailyArt app](https://www.getdailyart.com/) as an example, which is exactly what I am looking for.

I currently have a page that dynamically displays content from a Firestore Database. So, I am missing the part where the user can click a button to get the previous day content, and if there is a next day content available, then show the "Next day" button.

I tried using a `DateTime` function as explained in [this article](https://community.flutterflow.io/c/discuss-and-get-help/firestore-documents-based-on-date-days-from-now) of the FlutterFlow's Documentation. I also attempted to play with different page states, but I have to say, this is quite new to me. So, I am probably in need of a new way of thinking this. I am not sure how to achieve this, and if it is even possible.

Thanks for your help,